# Do the BatchApexErrorEvent fields AsyncApexJobId and RequestId differ?

Tags: batchapexerrorevent

In the [BatchApexErrorEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_batchapexerrorevent.htm) documentation these two fields are described:

- `AsyncApexJobId` - The AsyncApexJob record for the batch Apex job that fired this event.
- `RequestId` - The unique ID of the batch job that fired the event. Event monitoring customers can use this information to correlate the error with logging information.

Are they always the same value, or if they differ what is the difference?

(I'm trying to fully understand the information provided in this event to improve some error handling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do.  Here is a log entry from my BatchApexErrorEvent handler

```
{
"type":"BatchApexErrorEvent",
"url":"/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/BatchApexErrorEvent/4"},

"ExceptionType":"System.UnexpectedException",
"Phase":"EXECUTE",
"Message":"An error has occurred while processing your request.",
"RequestId":"4mjXO0WqGv7mgfX2-s",
"CreatedById":"0055C000000eKHcQAM",
"ReplayId":"4",
"EventUuid":"47e6a547-a6a2-4a3e-8854-0d39fd1b896f",
"CreatedDate":"2022-11-28T23:10:39.000+0000",
"AsyncApexJobId":"7075C00001ir5xa",
"DoesExceedJobScopeMaxLength":false
}
```

Comment: So the `AsyncApexJobId` is an AsyncApexJob table row Id that can be used to query that table. Any idea how the `RequestId` can be used?

Comment: @KeithC I'm guessing [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_batchapexerrorevent.htm) don't help you here?

Comment: Keith - no idea on how to use the requestId - one would have to use query all the events of each type by that Id to know what information is available - I did not go through that exercise - we collect our events in Sumo Logic and the query could be done there or in a similar data warehouse